# Pandas groupby apply too slow. Suggest improvements / alternatives

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

**Input Dataframe:**

```
      ff    pp           xx     yy
0   10000   IVR     -19.6000    0.9700
1   10000   IVL     -19.8100    11.0900
2   10000   RV      -19.8500    -10.0300
3   10000   LV      -20.1500    23.3100
4   10001   RV      -19.8700    -10.0100
5   10001   IVR     -19.5900    0.9900
6   10001   IVL     -19.8100    11.0700
7   10001   LV      -20.1600    23.3300
8   10002   RV      -19.8900    -10.0000
9   10002   IVR     -19.5700    1.0100
10  10002   IVL     -19.8200    11.0500
11  10002   LV      -20.1800    23.3600
12  10003   IVR     -19.5400    1.0300
13  10003   RV      -19.9100    -9.9800
14  10003   IVL     -19.8200    11.0300
15  10003   LV      -20.1900    23.3700
16  10004   RV      -19.9400    -9.9600
17  10004   IVR     -19.5000    1.0600
18  10004   IVL     -19.8400    11.0100
19  10004   LV      -20.2000    23.4000
```

**Output Dataframe:**

```
     ff     x_min_LV    x_min_RV    x_max_LV    x_max_RV    y_min_LV    y_min_RV    y_max_LV    y_max_RV
0   10000   0.3400      0.0400      0.5500      0.2500      12.2200     11.0000     22.3400     21.1200
1   10001   0.3500      0.0600      0.5700      0.2800      12.2600     11.0000     22.3400     21.0800
2   10002   0.3600      0.0700      0.6100      0.3200      12.3100     11.0100     22.3500     21.0500
3   10003   0.3700      0.0900      0.6500      0.3700      12.3400     11.0100     22.3400     21.0100
4   10004   0.3600      0.1000      0.7000      0.4400      12.3900     11.0200     22.3400     20.9700
```

**Logic explained:**

For each value of 'ff', it is required to create the following columns. (show in output df)

```
1. x_min_LV= minimum 'xx' value between (LV) and (IVR, IVL)

ex: 
when ff = 10000,
x_min_LV = (-20.1500) - (-19.8100) = -0.34
np.abs(x_min_LV) = 0.34


2. x_max_LV= maximum 'xx' value between (LV) and (IVR, IVL)

ex: 

when ff = 10000,
x_max_LV = (-20.1500) - (-19.6000) = -0.55
np.abs(x_max_LV) = 0.55

3. y_min_RV= minimum 'yy' value between (RV) and (IVR, IVL)

ex: when ff = 10000,

y_min_RV= (-10.03) - (0.97) = -11
np.abs(y_min_RV) = 11
```

and so on...

**Minimum Reproducible Example**

https://www.online-python.com/sXlef30Q1V

The current approach to code is rudimentary at best and solves it for me but takes 43s for 80k rows. I wanted to optimize time taken. Please suggest any optimizations or alternate methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting a lot of error's when trying to run your code. But one thing that could help is not importing the whole library, but just the functions you need:

```
from pandas import Series, read_csv, DataFrame
from numpy import abs

def funcxy(x, from_, to_):
    x_vals = Series(x['xx'].values, index=x['pp']).to_dict()
    min_x_value = {}
    max_x_value = {}

    y_vals = Series(x['yy'].values, index=x['pp']).to_dict()
    min_y_value = {}
    max_y_value = {}

    for position_wide in from_:
        min_x_value[position_wide] = 10000
        max_x_value[position_wide] = -10000
    
        min_y_value[position_wide] = 10000
        max_y_value[position_wide] = -10000
 
    for position_central in to_:
        if position_central in y_vals:
            value = y_vals[position_wide] - y_vals[position_central]

        if abs(value) < min_y_value[position_wide]:
            min_y_value[position_wide] = abs(value)

        if abs(value) > max_y_value[position_wide]:
            max_y_value[position_wide] = abs(value)
    
        value = x_vals[position_wide] - x_vals[position_central]

        if abs(value) < min_x_value[position_wide]:
            min_x_value[position_wide] = abs(value)

        if abs(value) > max_x_value[position_wide]:
            max_x_value[position_wide] = abs(value)

    return min_x_value, max_x_value, min_y_value, max_y_value

df = read_csv('test.csv')

fb_to_cb = df.groupby(['ff']).apply(lambda x: funcxy(x, ['LV', 'RV'], 
['IVL', 'IVZ', 'IVR']))
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.reset_index()
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.drop(columns= 
[0]).join(DataFrame(fb_to_cb[0].tolist()))
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.drop(columns= 
[0]).join(DataFrame(fb_to_cb[0].tolist())).rename(columns={'LV': 
'x_min_LV', 'RV': 'x_min_RV'})
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.drop(columns= 
[1]).join(DataFrame(fb_to_cb[1].tolist())).rename(columns={'LV': 
'x_max_LV', 'RV': 'x_max_RV'})
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.drop(columns= 
[2]).join(DataFrame(fb_to_cb[2].tolist())).rename(columns={'LV': 
'y_min_LV', 'RV': 'y_min_RV'})
fb_to_cb = fb_to_cb.drop(columns= 
[3]).join(DataFrame(fb_to_cb[3].tolist())).rename(columns={'LV': 
'y_max_LV', 'RV': 'y_max_RV'})
print(fb_to_cb)
```

Comment: what errors are you facing? maybe i can help

Comment: I get a key error, in line 30 (value = x_vals[position_wide] - x_vals[position_central]). The error is for the key: "IVZ"

Comment: You suggested this (i.e. only using `from ... import ...`) in another post and said that it would help speed up the code. While it may add some very minor improvement due to the namespace lookups, it is not significant enough in nearly all cases. It is standard practice to do `import numpy as np` and `import pandas as pd` rather than importing the individual functions you need.